# How to repeatedly pass arguments to a python file

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a python script which is run as follows:

```
python script.py -n name
```

Also, I have a file (or say list) which contains all the `name` values such as follows:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
...
...
name1000
```

So, I want to run the python script to pass all these names as the arguments. The dumbest and laziest way of doing this task is that I created a shell script (I wrote a python script to generate this content) say `run.sh` as follows:

```
python script.py -n name1
python script.py -n name2
python script.py -n name3
python script.py -n name4
........
........
python script.py -n name1000
```

and I run this shell script as `sh run.sh`.

I am sure that there must be a smarter/elegant way of doing this. Any tips?

Also, is it possible to free (clear) the python memory after each execution

Comment: Why would you use `sh` when you already have (and use) `python`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is the built in system function within awk and so:

```
awk '{ system("python script.py -n "$0) }' filename
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me the elegance and simplicity of ```awk```. This method does the job without choking anywhere. Accepted!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest passing a file location (e.g. `'names.txt'`) as the parameter to your python script when called from shell. Then within the python script, import the names and work with them one by one.

To your second question, if you wrap the logic of script.py in a function (e.g. called `script_function`) which takes param `name`, and call `script_function(name)` for each `name` in `'names.txt'`, you should keep your memory use down. The reason is that all the variables created in `script_function` would be local to that function call and deleted/replaced on the next function call for working with the next name.

Comment: I think you're right and the question is a [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
cat <file_with_list_of_names_1_per_line> | xargs python script.py -n
```

that should do it, if not ... try wrapping "python script.py -n" in a bash script. Something simple, let say a script named "call_my_script.sh" which would contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
python script.py -n $1
```

, then you could call it with:

```
cat <file_with_list_of_names_1_per_line> | xargs call_my_script.sh
# this will call/execute "call_my_script.sh name", for each name in the file, 1 at a time
```

You could also use the "-P" option of "xargs", to run several instances in parallel (watch out for concurențial access to resources, like writing to same output file or similar, could produce strange results)

```
.. | xargs -P <n> ...
```

to run "n" instances of the script in parallel

Side note: also an important aspect for whom is not familiar with "xargs", it will treat each ***word*** individually, meaning if on a line there would've been 2 (or more) words "word1 word2" ... that would make it call "the script" 2 (or more) times, 1 for each word. It might not be the expected behavior, so it worth mentioning.

Comment: what does ```python script.py -n $1``` or how would I run that?

Comment: comments don't allow code snipets, so I've edited the original answer

Comment: Save yourself from the UUOC Award and use `<file_with_list xargs python ...` instead of `cat file | xargs .. ` ;)

Comment: actually had to search the acronym :D. 

I didn't knew this "trick", thanks, I'll keep it in mind and read mmore about it; although I think the "cat form" it's easier to understand by novices ... it's more "human readable".

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a list of names you can do the following in shell script

```
list="name1 name2 name 3 ... name1000"
for i in $list; do
python script.py -n $i
done
```